# Video file duplicate finder (based on length/duration)

Tags: windows, video, search, duplicate-files

I am looking for a program that will find duplicate videos based on duration (eg number of seconds) and not based on size/MD5/thumbnails/etc. This is a very simple concept but I find it impossible to find a program that can do this.

Although a standalone program would be the best option, I will settle for a script at this point.

OS: Windows

Comment: I'm curious why an MD5 match would not be suitable. If the MD5 is the same, it's more likely to be a duplicate than if the file size and duration match. Especially if the same video system created several files of exactly the same duration.

Comment: @Ring maybe the asker knows for a fact that none of their videos have the same length?

Comment: A script is a standalone program. Did you mean a GUI program? If yes please edit your question, thanks! :-)

Comment: @Ring checksum is too specific. any small change to a file will alter its MD5 (eg adding/removing metadata in the case of a video file)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul maybe script is not the correct word but I didn't mean GUI either. I was talking about a set of commands that will perform the function that I'm looking for on a non-specific program like ffmpeg.